# Mysql server going down frequently

Tags: mysql

Below given is the mysql error log I am getting. Our application is getting only 10-20 request per second, but every half an hour I am getting this error in mysql logs and mysql stops automatically.

```
2014-10-29 16:52:01 5114  InnoDB: Encountered a problem with file .\ib_logfile1
2014-10-29 16:52:01 5114  InnoDB: Disk is full. Try to clean the disk to free space.
2014-10-29 16:52:01 5114  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 20756 in file fil0fil.cc     line 5475
InnoDB: Failing assertion: ret
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2014-10-29 16:52:17 44652 [ERROR] C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server     5.6/bin\mysqld: Sort aborted: Error writing file     'C:\DOCUME~1\NETWOR~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\MY8E87.tmp' (Errcode: 28 - No space left on device)
2014-10-29 16:52:21 44652 [ERROR] C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin\mysqld: Sort aborted: Error writing file  'C:\DOCUME~1\NETWOR~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\MY8E86.tmp' (Errcode: 28 - No space left on device)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you what seems to be wrong:

```
Disk is full. Try to clean the disk to free space.
```

Near the bottom of your error log this line appears:

```
 5.6/bin\mysqld: Sort aborted: Error writing file 'C:\DOCUME~1\NETWOR~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\MY8E87.tmp' 
     (Errcode: 28 - No space left on device)
```

To me, it looks like you're trying to do a sort operation (maybe to fulfill an `ORDER BY` clause in a query) and you're using up your temp space on your hard drive.  It looks like the MySQL is using the user temp directory of a NETWORK user on your server.

You might look in that directory `C:\DOCUME~1\NETWOR~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\` to see if there are lots of old junk temp files lurking around, and delete them.

I suspect this is going to be hard to track down after the crash; MySQL releases the temp space when it crashes.

You can tell MySQL to use a different disk for its temp space. See this for information. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/temporary-files.html

**There's another possibility**

It's explained in the error log you posted... maybe your table is corrupted and you can clear it out.

```
InnoDB: there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
```

Comment: As you specified I went and checked the file path(as you suspected mysql cleared all the files). But my concern is that, since the file path is in C: drive and my c drive do have 5 GB of free space, what can be the reason for showing (Errcode: 28 - No space left on device)

Comment: 5gb free space for temp files isn't very much in 2014. Can you get it up to 20 or 30 gb free and see if that stabilizes your system?

Comment: As you suggested I changed the temp folder variable TMP and TEMP to another drive having 400GB free space, but the problem still persist. The funny fact was the logs are showing C:\DOCUME~1\NETWOR~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ again even after changing. I cross checked other Environment variables both user and system and confirmed that no other temp variable is declared.

Comment: That's a start. Now you could follow up on the other possibility in your error log.

Answer (score 2):

`2014-10-29 16:52:01 5114  InnoDB: Disk is full. Try to clean the disk to free space.`

Its clearly memory issue. Increase memory of your system

Comment: I checked both hardisk space and memory usage of mysql, both are fine. And innodb ibdata1 file size is 1GB(could this be the problem, if yes can you tell me how to resolve it).